# Multiple color bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is get multiple colors in the navbar?
Currently the bar as is shown 
[image]

1. Navbar
2. Logo
3. Navbar

Except I can only seem to get one color

Here is the link to the code I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/ju47nkgu/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/dealers">Dealers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <br>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-10 col-centered">
        <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/FL53zwz.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-small yellow" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Building/<br>Trade</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Bandsaws</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Automotive</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Dust/<br>Vacuums</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Planers/<br>Thicknessers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Routers/<br>Morticers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Sanders/<br>Grinders</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Table saws</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Woodlathes</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">DIY</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS

```
body{
  margin-top: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}    


.divide-nav{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #428bca;
}

.divide-text{
    color:#fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.affix {
  top: 50px;
  width:100%;
}

.filler{
  min-height: 2000px;
}

.navbar-form {
   padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-collapse{
   padding-left:0; 
}
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I feel like this isn't being explained correctly. Wouldn't you just target yellow class to add the yellow background?

Answer (score 0):

Just add CSS rules with the required background color.

In your current case add the rules..

```
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 { background-color: lightgray; }
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

...and set the background color to whatever you like!